# How to show an enter key on a numeric input keyboard in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I have the following XAML snippet:

```
<TextBox MaxLength="3" Text="30" LostFocus="UpdateValue">
  <TextBox.InputScope>
    <InputScope >
      <InputScopeName NameValue="Number" />
    </InputScope>
  </TextBox.InputScope>
</TextBox>
```

This causes a numeric keyboard to appear when clicked on, but to close it after manipulation, I have to annoyingly tap outside of it. Is there a way to make it include something like an enter button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a [InputScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputscopenamevalue%28VS.95%29.aspx) for this but I can't check them right now.  You probably have hence the question.

If there isn't an [InputScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputscopenamevalue%28VS.95%29.aspx) you could add an application bar with a single 'done' button.  When the keyboard is displayed, display the application bar too.  When the user hits the 'done' app bar button you can hide the keyboard by setting focus to the page.

```
Page.Focus();
```

Another option, [A Numeric Input Control for Windows Phone](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2011/03/numeric-input-control-for-windows-phone.html) 7.

Comment: What is an InputScope exactly? I can't really tell from the msdn site... And if I do it the way you said, would I have an ApplicationBar as usual with a round button?

Comment: InputScope changes the type of keyboard that pops up.  http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/windows-phone-7-inputscope-dictionary/574

Comment: And yes, on the phone look at settings for an email account for example, the toolbar will show a check and an 'x' for done and cancel.

Comment: Ah, I see. And today I noticed that the SIM PIN input when starting up my phone includes a small "ok" button above the keyboard. Do you know something about this by chance?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that can't be recreated by devs.

Comment: Ok, I guess I will utilize the Application Bar then. Thx a lot.